# How many equal partitions of the set are trivially unequal?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Suppose we have set $S=\{x_1,x_2,....,x_{2n-1},x_{2n}\}$
, where $x_1 < x_2 ..... <x_{2n-1}< x_{2n}$

We have non-empty disjoint subsets $A$ and $B$ both having size $n$.

Question is, how many pairs of such subsets will be trivially unequal? (By "unequal" we mean that sum of elements in subset $A$ doesn't equal to the sum of elements in subset $B$)

e.g. consider $S = \{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\}$

For $S$ with size $4$, three pairs are possible (ignoring duplicates), i.e:
$$1.\{x_1,x_2\}, \{x_3,x_4\}$$
$$2.\{x_1,x_3\}, \{x_2,x_4\}$$
$$3.\{x_1,x_4\}, \{x_2,x_3\}$$

As we can see, two pairs above will be trivially unequal:

$\{x_1,x_2\}, \{x_3,x_4\}$ (because $x_1 < x_3$ and $x_2 < x_4$ so $x_1 + x_2 < x_3 + x_4$)

$\{x_1,x_3\}, \{x_2,x_4\}$ (because $x_1 < x_2$ and $x_3 < x_4$ so $x_1 + x_3 < x_2 + x_4$)

To solve that using code is pretty straightforward, but I'm interested in purely mathematical solution.
Being unable to come up with the anything myself, I looked up the answers provided by the other users. A lot of them came up with the solution which uses "grid" method, for example one of the answers provided by the user:

> First, some observations.  If elements of the set are assigned in ascending order to subset A, subset B, or discarded, and every element of A can be paired with an element of B that was selected later, then A's sum will be smaller than B's, and the comparison will not be necessary.
>
> If you imagine a walk on a grid from upper left to lower right, where selecting an element for subset A is like walking East, and selecting an element for subset B is like walking South, and selecting an element for neither subset is effectively the same as selecting it for both (East, then South), then a walk that crosses the diagonal from north to south (with this direction being the first diagonal crossing) corresponds exactly to a subset pair that must be compared.

Can someone explain what this "grid" logic is?

Comment: What source are you quoting from?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem#Variant:_ties_allowed

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: @bof The question is related to the Project Euler's problem 107, link: https://projecteuler.net/problem=106

Comment: Put that reference and link in the question.